# UIProgressView for preloading app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiprogressview

Does anyone know of any tutorials for making a loading bar that animates as the app is loading? I can't find anything anywhere besides animating it with a button which I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone app loading works like this.

On launch it puts up the 'Launch Image' png image, that you specify in your build settings. (A cool trick is to make that a screen shot your first screen. It makes your app look like it launch instantly).

Then control passes to your Main.m function, which builds your windows.

What you will want to do, is set your launch image. Then build a new view which you call off your main.m function.

Check out Erica Sadun's Iphone Cookbook for more details. (Or just browse though the source code, she builds almost all of her apps off the Main.m).

Comment: It looks like Robert is addressing the question you asked. If I understand you correctly, your point is about "while the app is loading" as in before the program is ready to interact with the user. I have wondered about the same thing, and doing this from main.m may be how to go about it. Robert, I browsed the code of on Sudan's iPhone Cookbook, and can't find this particular matter. Can you be more specific on where to find it.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIProgressView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on using UIProgressView are pretty clear.

In your case, load up your first view controller from your app delegate, so that it is visible for displaying your UIProgressBar while the rest of the app loads.

Then begin the rest of the app data loading (whatever it may be).

The progress of a UIProgressView is represented by a float between 0 and 1.0.

To set the progress, call:

```
[self.progressView setProgress:0.4 animated:YES];  
//progressView is an IBOutlet and @property defined in the header file, and instantiated in viewDidLoad
```

Comment: so would I put code in all my classes to update the progress view as they are loaded?

Comment: Only if your classes contain your data (i.e. your 'model' in the MVC programming paradigm).  I'm assuming you have a lot of data that you're either loading from the web, or loading data from file to memory, etc.  If you're just loading up a simple app without any significant data or external resources then you shouldn't need to show any progress.